# How can I switch line-wrapping on and off from within less

Tags: console, less

I know I can run `less -S` and avoid long line wrapping. But can I switch wrapping on and off from within `less`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  You can toggle the `chop` behavior within `less`.

<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> would toggle the *chop long lines* behavior within `less`.

Comment: ... and there's nothing shorter than prepending a minus?

Comment: @einpoklum No.  Nothing shorter.