# "less" stopped wrapping on Debian Bookworm

Tags: less, debian-bookworm, utility

As it says in subject: it does NOT wrap text in terminal anymore and there does not seem to be any option in manpage that says how to force it to wrap long lines.

Please advise how to force `less` to wrap lines.

Comment: [How can I make Unix Less wrap long columns?](https://superuser.com/q/365418/241386), [How to turn off word-wrap in less](https://superuser.com/q/272818/241386). And it can also be turned on/off on-the-fly: [Turning off word-wrap with less during paging?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475005/44425), [How can I switch line-wrapping on and off from within less](https://superuser.com/q/735036/241386)

Comment: @phuclv "chop" is not "wrap", either toggle from within less or in options.

Comment: @harrymc Read the link: it's clearly about chopping, not wrapping.